# grouping records conditionally

Tags: mysql, sql

My Google-fu is coming up short on this one. I've got a table of transactions, like this:

```
id      email                   source      amount  timestamp
1       daniel@example.com      vendor      10      2014-03-10 23:34:40
2       john@example.com        website     15      2014-03-11 13:30:00
3       mary@example.com        website     50      2014-03-11 17:30:00
4       daniel@example.com      website     65      2014-03-13 20:06:30
5       mary@example.com        vendor      10      2014-03-14 16:20:30
```

I want to be able to group these by email, but only for users who:
A) came in through the 'vendor' source initially, and 
B) also made a transaction through the 'website' source. 
*So for the above sample data, I would want this:*

```
email                       total_amount        transactions
daniel@example.com          75                  2
```

Mary would not be included because her first transaction was through 'website', and not 'vendor'. John would not be included because he did not have a transaction through the vendor at all.

EDIT:

Less ideal, but still useful, would be this result set:

```
email                       total_amount        transactions
daniel@example.com          75                  2
mary@example.com            60                  2
```

Where Mary and Daniel are both included because they both came in through the 'vendor' source in at least one transaction.

Comment: Are there only 2 entries per email? or could vendor be listed then website twice, or vendor then website then vendor... (based on timestamps of course)

Comment: @xQbert could be one or many entries, with no telling about whether vendor or website source was first.

I should note that 'vendor' being in the user's first transaction is ideal, but not crucial. The crucial thing is only including users where 'vendor' exists in one of the transactions.

Comment: So, the transaction count is everything with timestamp after the first vendor instance and totals?  Lets say daniel@example.com had a timestamp of 2014-03-01 13:00:00 and amount of 5 with source website.  Would the total expected be 80 with 3 transactions or 75 with 2?

Comment: @xQbert 80 with 3 transactions - count and total should be agnostic about source.

Comment: There's still too many unknowns for me.  so long as a user has ANY vendor entry we aggregrate the amounts and transaction count right?

Comment: @xQbert that would be nearly ideal, and certainly useful. Most ideal would be to only include emails where the first 'source' is 'vendor'.

Comment: What you have tried ?

Comment: @JDeveloper I played around with joining the table to itself like xQbert did in his answer, but I couldn't quite get it right. In fact right now my server is timing out while trying to perform the query, so I can't even tell for sure if it's working (talking to my host now).

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT A.Email, sum(B.Amount) as Total_Amount, count(B.time) as Transactions
FROM tableName A
INNER join tableName B 
 on A.Email=B.Email 
 AND A.source='vendor' 
Group By A.Email
```

Requirements are a bit unclear as you initially indicate the must initially come though vendor, but then you retract that statement later by adding mary.

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/bb4f9/1/0

If date/timestamps are important add an AND clause for A.Time<= B.Time and aggregrate the A.Amoun t and A.time and add those in like...

```
SELECT A.Email, sum(B.Amount)+ sum(A.Amount) as Total_Amount, count(B.time)+count(A.Time) as Transactions
FROM tableName A
INNER join tableName B 
 on A.Email=B.Email 
 AND A.source='vendor'
 and A.Time<=B.Time
Group By A.Email
```

But this assumes vendor entry will only occur once for each email

So this solution first finds a vendor entry (if there's more than one for an email address this will not return accurate counts) then it finds any entries for the same email address with a source of website occurring after that vendor entry and aggregates the totals for that email adding in the vendor entry totals.  While it works for the same data provided, it may not work as desired if multiple vendor entries exist for the same email.  Without understanding how the totals should occur or if multiple data exists, or understanding why you need this information based on this data, I can't think of a better option without making lots of assumptions.

```
SELECT A.Email, sum(B.Amount)+sum(A.Amount) as Total_Amount, 
count(B.time)+count(A.Time) as Transactions
FROM tableName A
INNER join tableName B 
 on A.Email=B.Email 
 AND A.source='vendor'
 AND A.Time < B.Time and B.Source='website'
Group By A.Email
```

Comment: Thanks, that looks good. Much shorter than I would have expected. I will play around with the first one.

Comment: yep that's it ! Up_One for you !

Answer (score 1):

This query should give you the desired result by using a subquery to find the persons that have an initial 'vendor' record followed by a 'website' record, before collecting the summary information from the records for these persons.

If you remove the lines marked with `-- *`, persons whose 'vendor' record is not their first one is also included.

```
SELECT email, SUM(amount) AS total_amount, COUNT(*) AS transactions
FROM transactions
WHERE email IN 
    (SELECT t1.email FROM transactions t1
    LEFT JOIN transactions t0                                -- * 
    ON t0.email = t1.email AND t0.timestamp < t1.timestamp   -- *
    LEFT JOIN transactions t2 
    ON t2.email = t1.email 
    WHERE  t1.source = 'vendor' AND t2.source = 'website'
    AND t0.email IS NULL                                     -- *
    )
GROUP BY email;
```

See http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/864898/8/0

Comment: Thanks, I will try this one out as well. Curious about the t0.email IS NULL though.

Comment: @user1020189  The marked lines joins each record (t1) to other records (t0) having the same email and an earlier timestamp. Since `LEFT JOIN` is used, empty fields for t0 is included when no matching record is found. `t0.email IS NULL` then selects the (t1) records having no preceding record with the same email, i.e. the first record for each email.

Answer (score 0):

**Your query should look like this :**

```
select email, sum(amount) ,count(*)
from tbl 
 where email='daniel@example.com'
group by email;
```

*OR - to count all email !*

```
select email, sum(amount) ,count(*)
from tbl 
group by email;
```

*All by vendor*

```
    select email, sum(amount) ,count(*)
    from tbl 
 where source ='vendor' 
    group by email;
```

Also demo here:
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/de36ed/2

Comment: i hate down-voters who don't motivate their down-vote ! whats wrong with my answer ?

Comment: So the grouping is not the biggest issue - my problem is only including groups conditionally, where one of the records in the group contains a particular value (and ideally it should be the first in the group).

Comment: i am not sure i understand ! can you use order by ?

Comment: Add a `HAVING COUNT(id)>1`

Comment: @Mihai so I thought about using HAVING, but that is applied after grouping, right?

Comment: Yes,HAVING refers to groups just as WHERE refers to SELECT

Answer (score 0):

Try this :-

```
select x1.email_id,(x1.tot + x2.tot)as total_amount,(x1.cnt + x2.cnt)as transactions from 
(select t1.email_id,count(t1.email_id)as cnt,sum(t1.totalamt)as tot from testdata t1 where t1.sourcee='web' group by t1.email_id)x1
inner join (select t2.email_id,count(t2.email_id)as cnt,sum(t2.totalamt)as tot from testdata t2 where t2.sourcee='vendor' group by t2.email_id)x2
on x1.email_id=x2.email_id group by x1.email_id;
```

Output :-

[image]

Its working fine.If required you please change the field name as per your table structure.
Hope it will help you.